Example of a T2 space that is not T3.
I am currently solving a problem where I need to bring up a counterexample in the form of a T2 space that is not T3. The Wikipedia page of T3 brings an example that states: " There exist Hausdorff spaces that are not regular. An example is the set $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by sets of the form $U\backslash C$, where $U$ is an open set in the usual sense, and $C$ is a fixed nonclosed subset of R with empty interior. "
Let $C = \left\lbrace \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$, what would be a closed set $K$ and a point $p$ such that there is no $U_K\supset K$ and $U_x\supset\lbrace x\rbrace$ open with $U_K\cap U_x\neq\varnothing$?
Is there something I am missing?
Thank you in advance for your answers.
Edit 1:
Reading again the example given by Wikipedia it seems like it isn't even T2! Any point in $C$ is never contained in any open set!
Edit 2:
The Wikipedia Page has now been fixed. Thank you @PatrickR.

There might be a typo. The topology should also include all sets that are also open in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

As discussed, the topology is not only not $T_2$, it is not even $T_0$, because points in $C$ are topologically indistinguishable.

Well, then I don't get why this is an example in the Wikipedia page...

You are correct that the example in Wikipedia is invalid.  The correct definition for the topology to make this work is given in the answer by Alman.

I have now fixed the incorrect example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space.

Adding this for clarification.
There may be a mistake. Let's denote your space $\mathbb{R}_C$. Sets that are open in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the standard topology) should also be open in $\mathbb{R}_C$. Note that this topology is strictly finer than $\mathbb{R}$.
It is easy to check that $\mathbb{R}_C$ is Hausdorff by the following straightforward fact:

If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is Hausdorff and $(X, \mathcal{T}')$ is finer (i.e., $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}'$), then $(X, \mathcal{T}')$ is Hausdorff.

To see that $\mathbb{R}_C$ is not $T_3$ (regular (Hausdorff)), consider the obvious point $p = 0$ and the closed set $C$ (which misses $p$). We claim that there is no neighborhood of $p$ disjoint from an open set containing $C$. Consider a basis element containing $p$. It must be of the form $B'_\varepsilon = (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) - C$, where $\varepsilon > 0$ (otherwise the basis element intersects $C$). Now, by Archimedean property, there is some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \implies \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$. Consider a basis element about $\frac{1}{n} \in C$; it must be of the form $B_\delta = \left( \frac{1}{n} - \delta, \frac{1}{n} + \delta \right)$, where $\delta > 0$. If $\delta \le \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1} = \frac{1}{n (n + 1)}$, then the point $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2} \delta \in B'_\varepsilon \cap B_\delta$. Otherwise, the point $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n + 1} \right) \in B'_\varepsilon \cap B_\delta$. So, $p$ cannot be separated from $C$ by open sets.
N.B. This is actually a well-known topology, and it is called the $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$. (The set $C$ you defined is called $K$.)

Thank you for your fast and very clear answer. Your proof of why C is not contained in any open supset completes the answer of @Alman. Have a great time!

Instead of considering the topology generated by the sets of the form $U \setminus C$, with $U$ an usual open and $C = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, consider the topology generated by the sets of the form $U \setminus V$, with $U$ an usual open and $V \subseteq C = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. (See the definition here: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000056).
Let $U$ be an usual open, $U$ is open in this topology too ($U = U \setminus \emptyset$). Since this topology is finer than the usual and the usual is Hausdorff, this one is Hausdorff too.
But $C$ is closed in this topology (it is clear that $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$ is open by definition of this topology), $0 \notin C$, and $0$ and $C$ can't be separated by disjoint neighborhoods.

Thank you for your fast and concise answer. This is exactly what I looked for!
Have a great time!

You're welcome, sir.  I'm glad about that.
Notice how, under the same reasoning, you can deduce that, as the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is Functionally Hausdorff, and as the new topology that we have defined is finer than the usual, then it is also Functionally Hausdorff. This is a stronger separation axiom than Hausdorff.
I hope you have a great time too.

@K. Jiang's answer is more complete. However I hope time will upvote your Answer to the top as it immediately gives a clear intuition to the answer.

Fair enough. Thank you, sir.

For examples, look at pi-base
Filter by formula "Hausdorff + ~Regular" to find many of these examples.

WOW! This is a great website!
Thank you for your fast and clear answer.
As a good example, if you want, you could add the "deleted diameter" topology which I think is very intuitive.
Have a great time!
